# Angular unit testing in routing and routerLink using Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes, jasmine

I am new in Angular and unit testing. I create a new project for testing the routing in Angular.I follow the guide in [Angular official doc](https://angular.io/guide/testing#components-with-routerlink).It does work in testing the routerLink.

but here is a problem. I forgot creating a route in the app.routing.module.ts, 
but the test still pass.

here is the code
in routing.module.ts

`const routes: Routes = [];`

and in html

`<a routerLink="/order">Order</a><br/>
<a routerLink="/creditCard">Credit Card</a>`

in spec.ts

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;
  let app: any;
  let compiled: any;
  let linkDes:any;
  let routerLinks:any;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        RouterLinkDirectiveStub
      ]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      fixture.detectChanges();
      compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;

      // find DebugElements with an attached RouterLinkStubDirective
      linkDes = fixture.debugElement
        .queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkDirectiveStub));

      // get attached link directive instances
      // using each DebugElement's injector
      routerLinks = linkDes.map(de => de.injector.get(RouterLinkDirectiveStub));
    })
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it(`should have as title 'unitTesting'`, () => {
    expect(app.title).toEqual('unitTesting');
  });

  it('should render title in a h1 tag', () => {
    expect(compiled.querySelector('h1').textContent).toContain('Welcome to unitTesting!');
  });

  it('can get RouterLinks from page', () => {
    expect(routerLinks.length).toBe(2, 'should have 2 routerLinks');
    expect(routerLinks[0].linkParams).toBe('/order');
    expect(routerLinks[1].linkParams).toBe('/creditCard');
  });

});
```

I understand the unit testing should be isolated.
but in some case, it should have connection in order to test.

I googled. but lot of answers just compare with static path.

and my question is, how to test in scenario like below:

1. in routing.module.ts

   const routes: Routes = [

   {path:"order",component:OrderComponent},
     {path:"creditCard",component:CreditcardComponent}

   ];

2.in two or more pages have same anchor tag 

`<a routerLink="/order">Order</a><br/>
<a routerLink="/creditCard">Credit Card</a>`

3.if someone change the path in routing.module.ts,like

`{path:"orderDetail",component:OrderComponent},`

and forgot to change the path of routerLink in all or one of html file, test case will still pass for those component that forgot to change the path of routerLink.

Therefore, what to do to fix it to show failure in test case.